# Running multiple instances of the same process on each node

Tags: kubernetes

I have executable which I need to run 10 processes of on each node and each of those processes should be exposed to public on their own port.
So, I create container with this executable. Then, I guess I need to create Service with type NodePort and Deployment for it. However, I'm not sure how to make it so that each node will run exactly 10 of them (and there are many nodes too) and how to make it so that each Pod/Container/Process will be exposed on their own port.

Also, process inside contrainer should somehow be able to know on which port it's exposed.

Comment: you can try to look daemonset

Comment: @c4f4t0r So I need to create 10 DaemonSets each with their own Pod/Container and specified port?

Comment: Daemonset you can have one pod by node = "A DaemonSet ensures that all (or some) Nodes run a copy of a Pod. As nodes are added to the cluster, Pods are added to them. As nodes are removed from the cluster, those Pods are garbage collected. Deleting a DaemonSet will clean up the Pods it created."

Comment: With Daemonset, would you then correlate 1 container per process? So 10 containers per pod each with their own port? Curious why you need exactly 10 prcesses per node?

Comment: What you're explaining completely defeats the purpose of using K8s as an orchestrator to abstract IP/port exposure, load balancing, no. of pods, etc.

Comment: can you add more details about this scenario, it seems like you are trying to achieve something which is not in line with Kubernetes. Present the goal maybe so we can help adjust it to Kubernetes.